# how can i see the changes(git commits) between two TeamCity builds of my choice

Tags: teamcity

I know that in TeamCity I can view changes between a certain build and the build that follows him and even between a certain build to the last successful Build.

I wanted to know if I can see the changes (git commits) between two TeamCity builds of my choice.

**example:** Build 1.0.2  to Build 1.0.97

Thanks.

Comment: Why not using git direct? git diff version_1 version_2

Comment: i want to see it on TeamCity, as i see it on the Changes colum

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming it is the same Build Configuration and you can go to the **Change Log** tab and then type in the **From** and the **To** build numbers and then hit **Filter**.

In TeamCity 7 it looks like this:
[image: TeamCity 7 Look]

And in TeamCity 8 you have to click **Advanced Search** then it looks like this:
[image: TeamCity 8 Look]

Comment: Is there a REST api for this?